# Using regular expression to remove commonly used company suffixes from a list of companies

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have the following code that I use to generate a list of common company suffixes below:

```
import re
from cleanco import typesources, 
import string

def generate_common_suffixes():
    unique_items = []
    company_suffixes_raw = typesources()
    for item in company_suffixes_raw:
        for i in item:
            if i.lower() not in unique_items:
                unique_items.append(i.lower())

    unique_items.extend(['holding'])
    return unique_items
```

I'm then trying to use the following code to remove those suffixes from a list of company names

```
company_name = ['SAMSUNG ÃŠLECTRONICS Holding, LTD', 'Apple inc',
                'FIIG Securities Limited Asset Management Arm',
                'First Eagle Alternative Credit, LLC', 'Global Credit 
                 Investments','Seatown', 'Sona Asset Management']

suffixes = generate_common_suffixes()

cleaned_names = []

for company in company_name:
    for suffix in suffixes:
        new = re.sub(r'\b{}\b'.format(re.escape(suffix)), '', company)
    cleaned_names.append(new)
```

I keep getting a list of unchanged company names despite knowing that the suffixes are there.

**Alternate Attempt**

I've also tried an alternate method where I'd look for the word and replace it without `regex,` but i couldn't figure out why it was removing parts of the company name itself - for example, it would remove the first 3 letters in Samsung

```
 for word in common_words:
        name = name.replace(word, "")
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `unique_items.append(i.lower())` but the suffixes are in caps ("LLC", "LTD", etc) Try adding `flags=re.IGNORECASE`

Comment: Also, I just looked up the `cleanco` lib. It already has a function `basename` that seems to do what you want.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp thank you so much! can you possibly take a quick look at the this link. I can't figure it out for the life of me but he uses basename first, then runs a similar regex that i posted to further remove names? I can't tell where defines suffix in his code and i've been stuck on this step for almost 2 days   https://medium.com/dnb-data-science-hub/company-name-matching-6a6330710334

Comment: i'm still getting the same unaltered list - is this the right syntax? 

new = re.sub(r'\b{}\b'.format(re.escape(suffix)), '', company, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

Comment: Ive even tried getting rid of i.lower completely from the generate_common_suffixes function and it's still the same issue

Comment: Just back from lunch. Based on the link you gave, I re-wrote your code. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import unicodedata
from cleanco import basename
import re

company_names = ['SAMSUNG ÃŠLECTRONICS Holding, LTD',
                 'Apple inc',
                 'FIIG Securities Limited Asset Management Arm',
                 'First Eagle Alternative Credit, LLC',
                 'Global Credit Investments',
                 'Seatown',
                 'Sona Asset Management']

suffix = ["holding"] # "Common words"? You can add more

cleaned_names  = []
for company_name in company_names:
    # To Lower
    company_name = company_name.lower()
    # Fix unicode
    company_name = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', company_name).encode('ASCII', 'ignore').decode()
    # Remove punctuation
    company_name = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', company_name)
    # Remove suffixes
    company_name = basename(company_name)
    # Remove common words
    for word in suffix:
        company_name = re.sub(fr"\b{word}\b", '', company_name)
    # Save
    cleaned_names.append(company_name)

print(cleaned_names)
```

Ouput:

```
['samsung aalectronics ', 'apple', 'fiig securities limited asset management arm', 'first eagle alternative credit', 'global credit investments', 'seatown', 'sona asset management']
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the time and effort. I'm just trying to understand so i can learn from this. what was preventing my code from working? even with the ignorecase flag and removing the .lower() from the generate list function - i couldn't get it to work? Also, in the article, is the intention to use basename like you did here and then he assumes suffix is a list of common words that i'd provide?

Comment: I think the main issue with your code was `new = re.sub(r'\b{}\b'.format(re.escape(suffix)), '', company)`. Besides the issue with case, you are constantly overwriting the `new` variable so it will only keep the last value. Change it to `company = re.sub(r'\b{}\b'.format(re.escape(suffix)), '', company, flags=re.IGNORECASE)` and then `cleaned_names.append(company)`

Comment: The article doesn't show where `suffix` comes from so I assume you have to make it yourself.

Comment: you are the man - thank you again for your time and effort!

Comment: my mistake - ended up deleting the comment - was using the wrong code block. All set now - thank you!